# VBA - close/unwrap/retract a combobox list?

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I'm working on a dynamically filled Excel combobox (embeded in worksheet)

But sometimes when I update the list inside while it's already "dropdown/unwrap", the display gets crazy.

As I fill and check the list, I use these :

1. to adjust the number of visible lines

   ```
   If .ListCount > 14 Then
       .ListRows = 15
   Else
       .ListRows = .ListCount + 1
   End If
   ```
2. to display/unwrap the list (anyCB is an Object parameter in my Sub)

   ```
   anyCB.DropDown
   ```

But sometimes, there is still 15 visible lines but a litlle slider inside the big (15) one, to scroll through all the lines in a single one... :/

So I'm wondering if there is **any way to close/unwrap/retract the list** before changing the number of visible lines. On any other workaround (lost focus, ...) that you could suggest ;)

---

Here are screenshots of both strange cases that I've got :
[image: Display going wild !]

What should reproduce on a regular combobox :

```
    For i = 0 To 100
        anyCB.AddItem (i)
    Next i

    With anyCB
        If .ListCount > 14 Then
            .ListRows = 15
        Else
            .ListRows = .ListCount + 1
        End If
    End With
    anyCB.DropDown

    If .ListCount > 0 Then
        For i = .ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
            .RemoveItem i
        Next i
    End If
    For i = 0 To 100
        anyCB.AddItem (i)
    Next i
    anyCB.DropDown
```

Comment: Can you provide enough code and instructions that I can reproduce this please?

Comment: Could you show a screenshot?

Comment: `the display gets crazy.` Even I would be interested in a screenshot :P

Comment: @SiddharthRout : here you go maester ! :)

Comment: @QHarr : Sorry, added more details. Working with and embeded combobox in the worksheet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug. There are two ways you can take care of this

**WAY 1**

Store the values in an array and then bind the array to the combobox

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim MyAr(100)

    anyCB.Clear

    With anyCB
        '~~> This is required because if you run this
        '~~> procedure for the 2nd time with the dropdown
        '~~> visible then you will face the problem again
        .Activate

        For i = 0 To 100
            MyAr(i) = i
        Next i

        .List = MyAr
        DoEvents
        .DropDown
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

---

**WAY 2**

1. Call `.DropDown`
2. Select a Cell (*Sheeesh!!!*)
3. Call `.DropDown` again

For example

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim i As Long

    anyCB.Clear

    With anyCB
        For i = 0 To 100
            .AddItem (i)
        Next i

        If .ListCount > 14 Then
            .ListRows = 15
        Else
            .ListRows = .ListCount + 1
        End If

        .DropDown

        If .ListCount > 0 Then
            For i = .ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
                .RemoveItem i
            Next i
        End If

        For i = 0 To 100
            .AddItem (i)
        Next i

        .Activate
        .DropDown
        [A1].Activate
        .DropDown
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        '~~> Change the selection to another cell, so that it'll work multiple times
        Me.Range("A2").Activate
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        DoEvents
        anyCB.Activate
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Sry man, i've let the grace period pass by... :/
Took me a quite a lot of tries to make the cell activation (no wonders why I didn't find a way on myself, would never have done that on purpose ! :D ) works with all the events that I fire ! I've allowed myself to add an edit to your answer (change the selected cell, before going back to the combobox because this was working only once)
Didn't take the time (yet) to try with binded array, but does it update as you edit the array ?

Answer (score 2):

Is this by any chance similar to what you are seeing?

[image]

As you already mentioned, the solution is to remove the Focus from the ComboBox before adding items and adjusting its ListRows.

Try to call the following before adding items and changing the `.ListRows`

```
anyButton.SetFocus
```

and once you adjusted the `.ListRows` you may call

```
anyCB.DropDown
```

Complete code example

```
anyButton.SetFocus
For i = 0 To 100
    anyCB.AddItem (i)
Next i

With anyCB
    If .ListCount > 14 Then
        .ListRows = 15
    Else
        .ListRows = .ListCount + 1
    End If
End With
anyCB.DropDown
```

Comment: Thx for your input ! I think you're close but I'm sorry I didn't explained that I'm working with an embeded combobox in the worksheet. I can't find anything to focus in there... Didn't find the right control to use yet !